# Which STS key was used to upload data to s3?

Tags: amazon-s3, aws-sdk

How can I know given a S3 object, which STS key was used to upload it?

**Explaining my use case scenario (just FYI):**
In my application, I allow my users to upload data to s3 using the Javascript SDK. To initiate the SDK I provide my users with a `STS token` with a 15 min expiry.

Users are supposed to use that key once to upload **exactly 1 data** which my application later processes.

Problem is once I issue this token and give it to users, some malicious users may try to upload many random large data to my bucket.

Since just be seeing an object, I have no way to associate that data to a user, I do not know who the culprit it. If by some **magic** method I can ask aws to give me the key which was used to upload this data, then I can cross match that key to which user I had issued it to, thus finding my culprit.

1. I cannot use `metadata` because malicious user will not provide it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Enabling [AWS CloudTrail](https://aws.amazon.com/cloudtrail/) and/or enabling [S3 server logs](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/ServerLogs.html) should provide you with the appropriate logging to track this information.

Comment: Thank you for your response. As per this article (http://docs.aws.amazon.com/awscloudtrail/latest/userguide/cloudtrail-event-reference-user-identity.html#STS-API-SAML-WIF), only SAML and web-id-federation STS keys can be logged, however, I am using `getSessionToken()` to get my tokens, which do not fall under these categories. Any suggestions?

Comment: @Rash it sounds like you should not be using getSessionToken but should be using assumeRole, which would allow you to supply a policy statement to restrict the actions performed with the temporary credentials down to only a single key in a single bucket, even from a single source IP if you desired.  Exposing a session token appears to potentially give away too much privilege. *"Typically, you use GetSessionToken if you want to use MFA to protect programmatic calls to specific AWS APIs"* http://docs.aws.amazon.com/STS/latest/APIReference/API_GetSessionToken.html

Comment: @Michael-sqlbot I am not too worried about using `GetSessionToken()` because the IAM role that is producing these tokens itself has the permission to only upload the object to specific bucket and key, thus all resulting temp creds also are bound to these restrictions. `GetSessionToken` seems to be the most basic form of token not giving the temp creds any power at all. `AssumedRole` on the other hand seems bulky and un-necessary at this point. I liked the idea of S3 logs, but I don't see the logs including STS keys in there.

Comment: "Bulky and unnecessary" would have prevented the problem you're now trying to find and fix after the fact.  Curiously, according to the [docs](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/id_credentials_temp_request.html#stsapi_comparison), you shouldn't be able to getSessionToken using an instance role, because those credentials are obtained using assumeRole.  Strange.  CloudTrail should have what you are looking for though.

Comment: @Michael-sqlbot You were absolutely right. For testing purpose I was using my admin account to generate STS tokens thinking that later I will use lower privileged account to generate tokens. I did not realize the account will need `AssumeRole` permission to generate tokens in first place. So I moved on to using `AssumeRole` today and have created users accordingly. This also solves your mystery of why I was able to get session tokens using an instance role. Thanks for your help :)